# Entity Framework : delete all entities from collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Identity in an ASP.NET MVC application.

My identity model is (involved part):

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; 
}
```

I'm getting a user like that :

```
    ApplicationUser signedUser = UserManager.FindById(model.Id);
```

Now I want to simply delete all the `Group` of this signedUser. I have tried a foreach loop but of course as collection is modified, it doesn't work.
I haven't got a `RemoveAll()` method for `signedUser.Groups`.

How to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming a group can have multiple users, and users can belong to multiple groups ( many-to-many relationship) you probably have a link table? If so, and assuming you want to remove a specific user from all the groups he belongs to, you would remove the link table records that refer to that user id.

Comment: Yes I have a link table but as I use Identity, i don't have any entity for this link table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. The point here is that it is a virtual property and in fact just a relation.

So to delete this relation I had to use :

```
signedUser.Groups.Clear();
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your unitOfWork to do the job for you:

```
unitOfWork.Groups.RemoveRange(signedUser.Groups);
```

or if you prefer to work with the dbset directly:

```
foreach(var group in signedUser.Groups)
{
   db.Entry(group).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
db.SaveChanges(); //After all the customer is deleted, Commit.
```

Comment: I don't want to remove a group but a group of the ApplicationUser and as mentioned, the foreach loop cannot be performed as collection is modified when item is deleted.

Comment: The fact that the setter on that EntityEntry 'State' property is public always surprised me - I can only assume the EF designers believe there are legitimate and safe reasons to modify it directly, though it's not clear what from the documentation (they hint it could be if you want to delete something without the expense of loading it).

Comment: Guess I don't clearly understand what you are trying to do. what do you mean by "I don't want to remove a group but a group of the ApplicationUser". But don't worry about the foreach loop that will work.